# Should I install Lapack and Eigen for OpenCV?

Tags: performance, opencv, compilation, lapack, eigen3

I'm trying to build OpenCV (4.5.1) from source, from the CMake-GUI output, there are 2 third-party libraries displayed as `NO`.

```
  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/Users/opencv-4.5.1/_build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/Users/opencv-4.5.1/_build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
```

I want best performance of OpenCV, so I'd like to check what's the performance gain if I install `Lapack` or `Eigen`?

Comment: I think I will skip Lapack, since it seems to need a FORTRAN compiler which I don't have in Windows.

Comment: Where did you hear that lapack or eigen will increase performance of opencv and how ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk That's my own assumption, I have to say. My logic is like this: if lapack or eigen will not improve performance, why not just remove it from opencv's 3rd party libraries, which are already way too many.

Comment: It's frustrating that nobody knows. Nobody knows what `WITH_LAPACK` and `WITH_EIGEN` do and they are left forever undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

The actual functions you get when eigen is enabled.

Eigen will allow you a specific set of matrix operations but I don't think many python opencv scripts use it therefore it is optional.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/daf/group__core__eigen.html